# How to access Singleton class's static method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop

I have some confusion with singleton class, below are my some points:

1. Can singleton class have static method?,if yes then how we call that methods?
2. what is main difference between Static class and Singleton Class?

I have created my singleton class as follows:

```
 public class Singleton
    {
        private static  Singleton _instance = null;
        private static object chekLock = new object();
        private Singleton()
        {}

        public static Singleton Instance
        {
            get
            {
                lock (chekLock)
                {
                    if (_instance == null)
                        _instance = new Singleton();
                    return _instance;
                }
            }
        }

        public static void StaticAddMethod()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Add Method");
        }

        public void AddMethod()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Add Method");
        }
    }
```

In Above class structure I have created two method one is Static and second is non static, When I am trying to access Static Method it gives me compile time error.

How can I use static method of singleton class?

Comment: It'd probably be helpful to list what you are trying to achieve by using a Singleton as that class isn't a Singleton, it's just a class with static methods in.

Comment: How are you trying to access the static method? you should be using Singleton.StaticAddMethod() what compile error do you get?

Comment: If you are running .NET 4 I'd look at using the `Lazy<T>` object with your Singleton. It's really nice and clean: http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2010/05/19/c-system.lazylttgt-and-the-singleton-design-pattern.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How are you trying to access it? To access a static method you use the type name:

```
Singleton.StaticAddMethod();
```

vs

```
Singleton.Instance.AddMethod();
```

Note also that there are simpler ways of implementing singletons that acheive the same effect with less locking etc.

Re the difference between singleton and static; a singleton might implement an interface, allowing you to pass it into existing code. You can also (as indeed you are doing) defer construction of a singleton (yet still allow access to the static methods that don't involve the singleton instance). But yes: there is a lot of crossover between static and singleton.

Comment: Just a comment on the "simpler ways of implementing singletons that achieve the same effect with less locking" part - [here's](http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/java-singleton-design-pattern) a good resource that includes a short explanation of how to make it thread-safe with the "synchronized" keyword.

Comment: @chrisf c# `lock` (per the question) means pretty-much the same thing. There is an attribute you can use that the JIT interprets the same as synchronised, but it is rare to see it in use.

Comment: Ah. I overlooked that part about it being C#. Apologies.

Answer (score 3):

Static methods can be called from the Type directly. You dont need to create an instance to do so.

So

```
Singleton.StaticAddMethod();
```

Will work

Also change your declaration from

```
private static  Singleton _instance = null;
```

to

```
private static READONLY  Singleton _instance = new Singelton();
```

This will allow you to get rid of all the locking you are doing, since the readonly can only be assigned on creation, protecting you from any locking you could run into ;)

```
public static Singleton Instance        
{            
    get
    {
        return _instance;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be accessing the static method via:

```
Singleton.StaticAddMethod()
```

Or, if you are already *inside* `Singleton`, then just:

```
StaticAddMethod()
```

The difference is that a static method is accessible from anywhere.  An instance method requires that you invoke the method on a created instance of your class.  With respect to a Singleton, it means that the class has *instance* fields/methods, but you can access the one-and-only instance via a static `Instance` property.

Answer (score 2):

Static methods belong to the type itself, not to the type's instance. So you can call static method like this:

```
Singleton.StaticAddMethod()
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
Singleton.StaticAddMethod();

Singleton.Instance.AddMethod();
```

Answer (score 0):

To your second question, one difference between the two is that a singleton class can be sublclassed and participate in polymorphic behavior in a way that a static class cannot.

Comment: Can you give me any example of subclassed and polymorphic behavior

Comment: With a static class, you might use it like MyStaticClass.DoSomething(); With a singleton, you could subclass it and use it like: MyClass.Instance.DoSomething();