# Unable to access static methods from singleton of static class

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, singleton

I've a class that has a singleton and a method as below:

```
public class ProductManager
    {
       private static ProductManager _Value = null;
        public static ProductManager Value
        {
            get { if (_Value == null) _Value = new ProductManager(); return _Value; }
        }


public static void SaveProduct(string productname)
        {
        }
}
```

I've another class in another assembly (SecondAssembly), that wraps around that class, like this :

```
public class BaseManager
    {

        public static FirstAssembly.ProductManager ProductManager
        {
            get
            {
                return FirstAssembly.ProductManager.Value;
            }
        }
}
```

In the same assembly (SecondAssembly), i want to access SaveProduct method of ProductManager class through this property of BaseManager. But i am unable to do so, it won't just show up :

```
BaseManager.ProductManager.SaveProduct("abc"); // Can't access it..
```

Please exaplain to me, why i cant do so ?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access static method via instance. It's a nonsense. You don't need an instance in this case. You can call just `ProductManager.SaveProduct(...)`

**EDIT:**
If you want to wrap `ProductManager` by `BaseManager` you can either make `SaveProduct` instance method instead of static or wrap `SaveProduct` in your `BaseManager`:

```
public class BaseManager
{
    ...
    public static SaveProduct(...)
    {
        ProductManager.SaveProduct(...);
    }
}
```

In my opinion it's better to make `SaveProduct` non-static since `ProductManager` is anyway singleton

Comment: Yes i know. But i want to wrap all my Manager classes into the BaseManager and access them all through this BaseManager class for all calls.

Comment: Thanks @ditskovich
But i dont think i can do that either. 
The purpose of having one BaseManager to wrap around those other managers from a different assembly is that later on, i will be calling those managers (including ProductManager) through WCF services. so for now i just want one class and all my methods to those managers should be called from that class. But i dont wanna make those methods in BaseManager. Your help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

static method is accessible from anywhere.

```
ProductManager.SaveProduct()
```

[SEE HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4206517/how-to-access-singleton-classs-static-method)